# Why is different benchmarks of HD/SD between hdparm and dd tool?

Tags: benchmarking

I see some tools to help benchmark HD/SD speed (**read** and **write**).

**hdparm** and **dd**

I did some benchmarks with these tools:

Input: buffered size = **932** MB

- Read speed with *dd*: **536** MB/s
- Write speed with *dd*: **492** MB/s
- Read speed with *hdparm*: **310.51** MB/s

## uncaching:

```
root@tech_expert:/home/tech_expert# hdparm -W0 /dev/sda5

/dev/sda5:
 setting drive write-caching to 0 (off)
 write-caching =  0 (off)
```

## read speed with hdparm (caches dropped)

```
root@tech_expert:/home/tech_expert# sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
root@tech_expert:/home/tech_expert# time sh -c "sudo hdparm -t /dev/sda5 && sync"

/dev/sda5:
 Timing buffered disk reads: 932 MB in  3.00 seconds = 310.51 MB/sec

real    0m6.229s
user    0m0.032s
sys     0m0.798s
```

## write speed with dd (caches dropped)

```
root@tech_expert:/home/tech_expert# sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
root@tech_expert:/home/tech_expert# time sh -c "dd if=/dev/zero of=test bs=8k count=113800 && sync"; rm -f test
113800+0 records in
113800+0 records out
932249600 bytes (932 MB, 889 MiB) copied, 1.89512 s, 492 MB/s

real    0m2.686s
user    0m0.018s
sys     0m0.904s
```

## read speed with hdparm (caches used)

```
root@tech_expert:/home/tech_expert# time sh -c "sudo hdparm -T /dev/sda5 && sync"

/dev/sda5:
 Timing cached reads:   23848 MB in  1.99 seconds = 11964.42 MB/sec

real    0m7.127s
user    0m0.260s
sys     0m1.781s
```

## read speed with dd (caches dropped)

Keep the "test" file and execute below command:

```
root@tech_expert:/home/tech_expert# time sh -c "dd if=test of=/dev/null bs=8k count=113800 && sync"
113800+0 records in
113800+0 records out
932249600 bytes (932 MB, 889 MiB) copied, 1.73958 s, 536 MB/s

real    0m1.775s
user    0m0.098s
sys     0m0.732s
```

## read speed with dd (caches used)

```
root@tech_expert:/home/tech_expert# time sh -c "dd if=test of=/dev/null bs=8k count=113800 && sync"
113800+0 records in
113800+0 records out
932249600 bytes (932 MB, 889 MiB) copied, 0.198455 s, 4.7 GB/s

real    0m0.230s
user    0m0.026s
sys     0m0.175s
```

There were big differences between 02 tools.

I don't know I should believe in which result is more trusty?

Comment: `bs=8k` is pretty small, still significant system call overhead.  Try at least 64k, or more like 128k (half of L2 cache size on an Intel CPU, so kernel->user `copy_to_user` will still get L2 cache hits).  That might not be a full explanation though, since in the cached read case with 8k reads you did get 4.7GB/s.  A fraction of DRAM bandwidth on a modern system, but much faster than your SSD.  Reminder: don't put too much unnecessary wear on your SSD benchmarking it.

Comment: Thank you for the ans. I did the test with bs=128k on my target, but same situation. For tool qualification, I prefer dd tool.